# how can you have the same form handle by javascript multiple times on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a thumb gallery where I am using ajax/javascript to submit a form per image to report the image as broken seamlessly along with php. The form and script is templated so the script is in the header and then the form is printed multiple times on the same page with a hidden field with a different id for the value per thumb. So basically this is what i have.

javascript in header

just a quick idea of the forms i have. Just a quick idea not what I actually have.

image1 followed by the form

image2 followed by the form

So when you hit the button it basically submits all of the forms at the same time. I am sure it can be fixed with a (this) or something like that so it only submits a single form at a time. Let me know please.

$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
var imgId = $("#imgId").val();
        var dataString = 'imgId='+ imgId;
        if(imgId==''){
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeIn(200).show();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/brokenImgReport.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(){
        });

```
    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();  
    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();  
    setTimeout(function() {  
        $('.success').fadeOut(200); }, 2000);  
    }  
    return false;  
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

in a page with multiple forms. You can refer individual form as an array element forms[0],forms[1] and likewise, on click of submit button. you can do

forms[0].submit

forms[1].submit

and likewise

Comment: never mind I guess I can't change it because it has urls in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('form.your_class_if_needed').submit( function(){
        do_your_stuff_here()
    })
})
```

Every form with class `your_class_if_needed` will have the function you define attached to its `submit` method. Within that function, `$(this)` will refer to each specific form -- not all of them. You can then easily select, process, and assemble your form fields and values within the context of each form, and submit them with `$.ajax()` or `$.post()`.

Comment: As you can see above I have 
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
so I'm using the class as the button. I'm clueless to javascript so i'm still not sure how to get it to work. My thumbs are dynamically created via php and range from 12 to thousands of images so I need the javascript to work per form. there will be as many forms as there are images sense the forms function is to mark the image it's with as a bad image in the data base. I'll add the exact html to the origional post to hopefully help you out more.

Comment: I'm suggesting you override the submit method of each form itself, rather than attach behavior to the submit button's click event.